# How do i find the percentage of the most common element in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been recently using `Counter().most_common` but the problem is that I need to turn the bit where it shows how much it came up into a percentage, for example:

```
[(2, 5), (10, 5)]
```

to:

```
[(2, 50%), (10, 50%)]
```

Is there any way of doing this using `Counter().most_common`, or any other method?

Here is part of my code:

```
    while count < int(DR):
        count = count + int(1)
        DV.append(random.randint(1, int(DI)))
    if count == int(DR):
        print ('\n(The Number that was rolled , the amount of times it came up):')
        global x
        print (Counter(DV).most_common(int((DI))))
```

Comment: What exactly have *you* tried? Where's your code, and what's the problem with it? What do you mean by percentage - this would usually be a float (`0.5` in this case)?

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to conert it to percentages. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean you don't know the maths, or how to implement it? Do you know what a percentage actually is?!

Comment: Your code doesn't explain the problem - there are variables that could be anything, and no attempt made to calculate a percentage. Provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know the maths, I just don't know how to change the part where it states how much a certain number came up. I know how to change it into a percentage, but im not sure how to do it in python code.

Comment: Now most of the code is irrelevant. **Read the article.** See also [this](http://sscce.org). If you know how to calculate a percentage, which part of the implementation can't you manage?

Comment: How i would put, in the language of python the amount of times a number came up in the form of a percentage using Counter().most_common

Comment: So "all of it"? If you really can't even *begin to think* how to iterate over the items in the counter, get the count for each one and divide it by the total number counted, I despair. And seriously, sort out your code example; we don't need everything you've ever written. Actually read the resources I'm suggesting.

Comment: `50%` -> `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` since it isn't a valid Python literal, perhaps you meant `.50`?

Comment: I have it all done know thanks to you guys :)                       def Fourth():
    for i in Counter(DV):
        print (int(i),('Had a percentage of') , Counter(DV)[int(i)] / int(len(DV)) * int((100)),('%')) this is what i ended up doing and it worked.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
l = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
c = Counter(l)
[(i, c[i] / len(l) * 100.0) for i in c]
```

Output, in the form `(element, % of total)`

```
[(1, 14.285714285714285),
 (2, 35.714285714285715),
 (3, 7.142857142857142), 
 (4, 7.142857142857142), 
 (10, 35.714285714285715)]
```

To list them in order you can use `collections.Counter.most_common`

```
>>> [(i, c[i] / len(l) * 100.0) for i, count in c.most_common()]
[(2, 35.714285714285715),
 (10, 35.714285714285715),
 (1, 14.285714285714285),
 (3, 7.142857142857142),
 (4, 7.142857142857142)]
```

Comment: Thanks :) I modified it a little bit to this  def Fourth(): for i in Counter(DV): print (int(i),('Had a percentage of') , Counter(DV)[int(i)] / int(len(DV)) * int((100)),('%'))

Comment: Is there a way I could also have it sort so that the elements with the highest percents print out first?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the original data, you can still accomplish this just with the `Counter`.

```
OrderedDict([(i, str(round(count / sum(c.values()) * 100.0, 3)) + '%') for i, count in c.most_common()])
```

Where:

- `i` is the item that was counted;
- `count` is the count of that item;
- `c` is the `Counter` object
- `3` is the precision of the percentage

Performance can be improved if `sum(c.values())` is moved outside of the list compression.